# Converting a string to a double in C# - sometimes incorrect format

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, double

I'm using asp.net and c# on a web page and trying to convert a value from a textbox into a double.

These values are latitude and longitude coordinates, already in the correct format, and I'm using the following code:

```
double OrigLat = Convert.ToDouble(txtLatitude.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double OrigLon = Convert.ToDouble(txtLongitude.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Following a similar question I put in the culture information, otherwise it would just be:

```
double OrigLat = Convert.ToDouble(txtLatitude.Text);
double OrigLon = Convert.ToDouble(txtLongitude.Text);
```

Now, the OrigLat works fine, but the OrigLon throws up an error half the time. Due to the actual locations we operate the longitude is normally a negative number, though they cannot exceed 10 characters in length. Funny thing is, it sometimes works okay and sometimes throws an error with the same numbers.

The error is an "Input string not in correct format". Are there any inherent limitations to doubles that I need to know about? The strings are definitely in a numerical format. Do they need less decimal points (can go up to about 10)?

Comment: Could you put the string values where the conversion fails ?

Comment: When you say "half the time", do you mean that the same input may or may not work, or that some numbers consistently work and some don't?

Comment: Are you sure you're using you're the correct decimal character consistently, i.e. `,`, or `.`?

Comment: I suggest you use double.tryparse and see why same number sometimes work and sometime fail. tryparse returns a bool if string could be converted or not

Comment: I'd have to do a bit more testing (we're using rather a lot of different coordinates) but it does seem like some numbers consistently work and some don't.

Comment: @qamar's comment is your answer.  `if(double.TryParse(txtLatitude.Text, out mydouble){/*success*/}`

Comment: @paqogomez - Only partially. That will keep it from erroring, but it won't explain why it's failing.

Comment: You should add a validator and don't assume the user typed in a correct value.  This is easy to achieve with `e.IsValid = double.TryParse(...)`

Comment: Okay, call me stupid. I *may* have been including "," when I've been running tests. This would explain it. Will try again more tomorrow as I'm just about to leave for the day. Thanks for your help - and patience. We'll see if I'm an idiot tomorrow :)

Comment: @Bobson correct, its the first step.  Seems clear that OP doesnt (didnt) know why it was failing, this would allow OP visibility into that.

Comment: Alright, it seems I was being an idiot. I was copying and pasting latitudes and longitudes over too quickly and missing the "," in the longitude when I copied them from a string for testing. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Double.TryParse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and see why same number sometimes work and sometime fail. TryParse returns a `bool` if string could be converted or not

Comment: Marked this as useful, though not as the answer because the correct answer is that I screw my head on correctly (was accidentally including "," in the longitude). To quote Homer Simpson, "d'oh!".